# How to properly call to retrofit service using rxJava?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

I'm trying to understand `rxJava` and I'm looking for an expert or someone with experience to try to solve my question, the thing is I've been using RxJava for a year, but only for `Retrofit` calls, I've been using `Disposable` and doing something like :

```
disposable = myService.myInterface.getData()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(this::handleResponse, this::handleError))
```

Ok, but when I'm searching on Google I saw people using `CompositeDisposable` and they instead of doing `disposable = ...` they are doing `compositeDisposable.add(....)` I'd like to know when to use each one, I also say `Single` is for returning either a value or an error, but what's the difference between `Observable` then? If `Single` can return also a `List<Object>`.

And in other example I'm using this :

```
private var subscription: Disposable? = null
subscription = model.result()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeWith(object : DisposableObserver<ListViewModel>() {
                override fun onNext(viewModel: ListViewModel) {
                    if (mView != null) {
                        mView!!.updateData(viewModel)
                    }
                }

                override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    if (mView != null) {
                        mView!!.showError()
                    }
                }

                override fun onComplete() {
                    if (mView != null) {
                        mView!!.hideProgressBar()
                    }
                }
            })
```

I noted that if I use the `add.(..)` thing in the `onStop()` I have to clear the `compositeDisposable`

And also I've been using `disposable` without the `onNext`, `onError` and `onComplete` could you guys let me know when use all of those?

Answer (score 0):

The core difference between `Observable` and `Single` is relatively easy to explain:

- An `Observable` can emit 0 to infinite values
- A `Single`, on the other hand, only emits 1 time

`CompositeDisposable` is advised over "regular" `Disposable` because you can **compose** `Disposables` with it. Why is this useful? Let's say you invoke 3 different network requests at the same time, then you can add all those `Disposables` to the `CompositeDisposable`. Now if you switch Activity for example, you don't want to continue those 3 requests. Therefor the `dispose()` function of the `CompositeDisposable` is called. It will remove all `Disposables` and does not allow new ones to be added. Contrary, there is also a function called `clear()` which does remove all Disposables as well but it allows new ones to be added.

So basically instead of manually removing all `Disposables` one by one, you can handle this with a single method call. Hence the `CompositeDisposable` could be imagined like a "Manager" for `Disposables`.

And even with using a regular `Disposable`, you should call the `dispose()` function. Otherwise you may continue running `Observables` despite being on a completely different part of the App.

Comment: But I'd like when to use `Disposable` and when to use `CompositeDisposable`, in which scenarios I mean.

Comment: Well if you only have one Observable use a regular Disposable. If there are many use a CompositeDisposable. If you havd 3 Observables and one of them should run for a longer period than the other then use a CompositeDisposable for the 2 and a regular Disposable for the one that is running longer. Longer here means for example that it should continue to run when the Activity changes whereas the other two are disposed. Just use a regular Disposable if you need more granular control

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have much confusion about RxJava. First gets familiar with RxJava concept specifically Observable, Single, Completeable etc. Which serving what purpose? With proper scheduler usage. Then things will be bit clear to you.

And `Disposable` is being used when you have only one subscription in our class or you want to handle all the subscriptions independently.

Use `CompositeDisposable` when you are putting all of your subscription together into a single disposable so that you can clear in a simple way based on lifecycle.

Comment: Do you know where I can get all of this information clear?

Comment: I learned all of these things from different source like blog, videos, sample good etc. So, Start with specific item and start learning using those source.

Comment: Do you have any sample code using MVP and rxJava so I can learn from?